# Seemingly Random Characters at End of Output When Using Scanner

Tags: java, java-8, java.util.scanner

The code below is intended to encrypt and decrypt messages input. When I encrypt and decrypt data, it sometimes works and at other times doesn't. The following is an example of the problems I am experiencing.

**Encryption**

[image: Encryption]

**Decryption**

[image: Decryption]

As you can see, when I try to decrypt, my program terminated and some gibberish is output into the console. What is the issue with my code?

I'm unsure if mentioning this helps, but I have Eclipse's file encoding set to UTF-8.

Please excuse any poor code. I'm still very much a beginner with Java and I'm puzzled as to why this is happening.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Transcrypt {

    static String mode = "",
                  msg,
                  key;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!mode.equals("e") && !mode.equals("d")) { // Ask for mode until equal to "e" or "d"
            System.out.print("Encrypt or decrypt? (e/d) ");
            mode = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        }

        System.out.print("Message: "); // Ask for message
        msg = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Passkey: "); // Ask for key
        key = input.nextLine();

        input.close();

        System.out.println(transcrypt(msg, key, mode.equals("d"))); // Transcrypt and output
    }

    public static String transcrypt(String msg, String key, boolean decode) {
        String result = "";

        for (int i=0; i<msg.length(); i++) {
            // Add or subtract Unicode index of key.charAt(i % key.length()) and/from msg.msg.charAt(i) and convert back to character
            result += (char) ((int) msg.charAt(i) + ((int) key.charAt(i % key.length())) * (decode ? -1 : 1));
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems to be some kind of terminal issue. Using binary characters in a terminal is not necessarily a good idea. You can always encode/decode your binary strings to base64 or hex though to work around console problems.

Comment: Alternatively, classic (16th century) Vigenere encrypts only letters and wraps around within the alphabet: X+A=Y, X+B=Z, X+C=A, X+D=B. Often with some other handling of spaces and nonletters, such as using X between words when ambiguous and substituting words STOP QUERY ONE TWO THREE etc. Also note Vigenere is easily broken if used for real texts of any significant length; see Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your encoded message looks like `"¼ÊßàãÊãæÑ×"`, but actually, it is `"¼Êßàã\u0085ÊãæÑ×\u0095"`.

Most notably, it contains the control character `0x85` in-between which has “new line” semantics. So when copying that string, you’re copying the control characters with it and when pasting into the console upon your application’s query for the message, you are basically entering `¼Êßàã` as message, the input committed via the “new line” control character, causing the subsequent query for the password to consume the trailing `ÊãæÑ×` characters.

The garbage you see right after the `Passkey:` output, is the result of your attempt to decode `¼Êßàã` using the key `ÊãæÑ×`, as there was no newline entered at this point as the characters being already in the console’s buffer have been used.

Generally, as already said by Nándor Előd Fekete in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390893/seemingly-random-characters-at-end-of-output-when-using-scanner#comment68034106_40390893), you should not write characters to the console, that are actually binary data, like the encoded string.

---

By the way, you shouldn’t declare variables as `static` fields that are actually local to a method, i.e. your `main` method. Further, you don’t need to cast `char` to `int` when doing computations. `char` values are already a subset of the `int` values.